How can I get the output of a TestOccurrence with the TeamCity REST API
I'm trying to get the output -- as in stdout -- of a test via the TeamCity REST API. This is visible in the TeamCity Web UI if you click on a test, it's called the "stacktrace" (but actually includes all stdout from the test). I don't see anything obvious in the TestOcurrence API docs, searching for either "log" or "stacktrace"...
The TestOcurrence object has a logAnchor field, but I also can't find a way to get the test log through the REST API. (Note that this old question actually doesn't answer the question posed in the title -- it shows how to download with a logged in HTTP user session, but attempting this with API credentials fails, since it is not part of the API)
